# How to have a method take vector<string>&& instead of vector<string>?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

I want to avoid taking copies of vector, and use rvalue references instead. These are the methods.

```
    bool GeckoChildProcessHost::SyncLaunch(std::vector<std::string> 
aExtraOpts, int aTimeoutMs) {
  if (!AsyncLaunch(std::move(aExtraOpts))) {
    return false;
  }
  return WaitUntilConnected(aTimeoutMs);
}

bool GeckoChildProcessHost::AsyncLaunch(std::vector<std::string> aExtraOpts) 
{
  PrepareLaunch();

#if defined(XP_MACOSX) && defined(MOZ_SANDBOX)
  if (IsMacSandboxLaunchEnabled()) {
    AppendMacSandboxParams(aExtraOpts);
  }
#endif

  MessageLoop* ioLoop = XRE_GetIOMessageLoop();

  MOZ_ASSERT(mHandlePromise == nullptr);
  mHandlePromise = new HandlePromise::Private(__func__);

  // Currently this can't fail (see the MOZ_ALWAYS_SUCCEEDS in
  // MessageLoop::PostTask_Helper), but in the future it possibly
  // could, in which case this method could return false.
  ioLoop->PostTask(NewNonOwningRunnableMethod<std::vector<std::string>>(
      "ipc::GeckoChildProcessHost::RunPerformAsyncLaunch", this,
      &GeckoChildProcessHost::RunPerformAsyncLaunch, aExtraOpts));

  return true;
}
```

How do I do this? Also I believe I would need change their callers to use move. How would I do that? 
Here is the code for one of the caller.

```
 bool GeckoChildProcessHost::LaunchAndWaitForProcessHandle( StringVector 
aExtraOpts) {
  if (!AsyncLaunch(std::move(aExtraOpts))) {
    return false;
  }

  MonitorAutoLock lock(mMonitor);
  while (mProcessState < PROCESS_CREATED) {
    lock.Wait();
  }
  MOZ_ASSERT(mProcessState == PROCESS_ERROR || mChildProcessHandle);

  return mProcessState < PROCESS_ERROR;
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: As far as the code you shown, the vector is indeed moved. Is there something else that is required?

Comment: Does your question make sense? Ask yourself what is the lifetime of the strings you are referencing? How do you know they have not been destroyed? Especially if they are RHS temporaries. While a `vector<string>` will initially copy the string values in, unless they are coming from RHS temporaries - in which case it will move in; it will do an efficient move of those string values if it has to reallocate itself, or you insert in the middle.

Comment: But nowhere is vector<string>&& specifically used. That's basically what I want to do.

Comment: It only really makes sense for `AsyncLaunch` to take `aExtraOps` by value (or by rvalue reference) if it plans to move `aExtraOps` somewhere else, such as into `NewNonOwningRunnableMethod`.  Moving it into `NewNon` isn't very useful unless it will in turn take `aExtraOps` by value.  If you don't have anywhere to move `aExtraOps` into, just take it by const reference.

Answer (score 0):

> But nowhere is vector&& specifically used. That's basically what I want to do.

Are you sure you want to do that? Here's something you wrote just before:

> I want to avoid taking copies of vector

So if I understand correctly, you want to move the vector instead of copying it.

The thing is you do everything correctly right now. You must not use rvalue reference yourself to move data. In fact using rvalue reference to your function parameter will prevent the move (it will pass by reference instead of move). Rvalue reference are used to implement move semantics. What you really want for moving a variable is to use `std::move` when passing it by value, causing the move, which you already do.

See, the move and copy constructor as being in the same overload set. There's an optimized version of "copy" that can be called when sending an rvalue to it. Sometimes you still want the compiler to choose the optimized version because you don't care what happen to your variable. The function `std::move` does that. Simply convert an lvalue to an rvalue. Then, the move constructor does the actual move.

In your code, you do that:

```
// no copy, even if AsyncLaunch is taking by
// value, since we 'move' into the value
!AsyncLaunch(std::move(aExtraOpts))
```

You cast `aExtraOpts` into an rvalue, which moves the data into the value parameter. If the function would take its argument by reference (or rvalue reference) then there would be no move at all, simply references.